# Prove that the involution function is onto

Tags: functions

**Question** -

Prove that the involution function is onto i.e $f(f(x))=x$ is onto on $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R.$

I know it is very easy but, ...
I know definition of onto function but not able to apply properly. I want clear this little thing, so I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Given $y\in\mathbb{R}$ you can explicitly construct an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$ by using the function $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $b= f(a)$. Then $$f(b)= f(f(a)) = a$$

So for each $a$ (in codomain) exists $b$ (in domain) such that $f(b)=a$ ...

Comment: Thankyou..now for f(f(x)) = 1/x from Q+ to Q+ ...I have done same way as yours but did not getting to desired definition...can you help pls

Comment: Let $b= f(1/a)$...