# A function $g: ℝ\toℝ$ satisfies $g(g(x))=x$ for all $x\inℝ$.

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I would like help with this exercise. Thanks in advance.

A function $g: ℝ\toℝ$ satisfies $g(g(x))=x$ for all $x\inℝ$.

a) Show that $g$ is injective.

Let $a\inℝ$ and $b\inℝ$. Then,

$$g(a)=g(b)$$
$$g(g(a))=g(g(b))$$
$$a=b$$

b) If $(3,4)$ is a point on the graph of $g$ find $g(4)$.

$$g(3)=4$$
$$g(g(3))=g(4)$$
$$3=g(4)$$

c) Show that $g$ is surjective.

How do I prove it is surjective?

Are parts (a) and (b) ok?

Comment: “Let $a \in \Bbb R$ and $b \in \Bbb R$. Then, $g(a) = g(b)$ …” Well, no. I would write “Let $a \in \Bbb R$ and $b \in \Bbb R$ *be such that* $g(a) = g(b)$. Then …”

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3599842/42969

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that if a function has an inverse then it's bijective. Here $g$ acts as its own inverse, so we immediately have part (a) and (c). Of course, this kind of trivializes the whole problem so it's probably not fair to use, but it's good to know!

Answer (score 0):

a) b) are fine. If $x$ is any real number then $y=g(x)$ is a real number such that $g(y)=x$. Hence, $g$ is surjective.

Comment: but how is $g(g(x))=x$ used there? Don't we have to use that for this part?

Comment: $g(y)=g(g(x))=x$. @bdvg2302

Comment: I don't understand that surjective proof. :-(

Comment: Pick any $x$ and let $z=g(x)$ then $g(z) = x$. Which is what was written above.

Comment: Do you know what surjective means? You give me some real number and I will show that the number is in the range of $g$.